# How to define a specific style for each page section?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Here, each section of a page should have its specific style. For example, in the code below, I'd like that the headers and paragraphs of `section-a` and `section-b` had, each, their own style. But it's not working with my approach.

There's no global styles for `<p>` and `<h2>` that could be conflicting with those from
`section-a` and `section-b`.

And I'd prefer not adding the style per line - like `<p id="section-a">` - to keep the code cleaner.

```css
h2 {
  font-family: 'Wellfleet', cursive;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
}

h2#section-a {
  color: red;
}

p#section-a {
  color: black;
}

h2#section-b {
  color: blue;
}

p#section-b {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="section-a">
  <h2>LOREM</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <a href="#">consectetur</a> consequat.</p>
</div>

<div id="section-b">
  <h2>LOREM</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <a href="#">consectetur</a> consequat.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should use the semantic `<section>`-tag for sections instead of `div's`. Then your selector is wrong. `h2#section-a` looks for an h2 elment with the id `section-a`. What you looking for as selector should be: `#section-a h2`:

```css
h2 {
  font-family: 'Wellfleet', cursive;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
}

#section-a h2 {
  color: red;
}

#section-a p {
  color: black;
}

#section-b h2 {
  color: blue;
}

#section-b p {
  color: white;
}


/* added for visualisation purpose */
body {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div id="section-a">
  <h2>LOREM</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <a href="#">consectetur</a> consequat.</p>
</div>

<div id="section-b">
  <h2>LOREM</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <a href="#">consectetur</a> consequat.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the order of your css selectors.

From `p#section-a`

To `#section-a p`

```css
h2 {
  font-family: 'Wellfleet', cursive;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
}

#section-a h2 {
  color: red;
}

#section-a p {
  color: black;
}

#section-b h2 {
  color: blue;
}

#section-b p {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="section-a">
  <h2>LOREM</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <a href="#">consectetur</a> consequat.</p>
</div>

<div id="section-b">
  <h2>LOREM</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <a href="#">consectetur</a> consequat.</p>
</div>
```